# How save images in local storage like text files and show it in recyclerview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to save text and images in local storage then show it in recycler view, Text files are saved but images not saving in local storage.

Code which take files from list

```
private void saveData() {
       String  Name_text=EName.toString().toUpperCase().trim();
       String  E_DES=E_Des.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
       String  EPrice=E_Price.toString().toUpperCase().trim();
       String  Esize=E_size.toString().toUpperCase().trim();
       Integer PIC= Integer.valueOf(mImageView.getResources().toString());

        {
            UserModel model=new UserModel();
            model.setProductName(Name_text);
            model.setImage(PIC);
            model.setProductDisc(E_DES);
            model.setProductPrice(EPrice);
            model.setProductSize(Esize);
            DatabaseClass.getDatabase(getApplicationContext()).getDao().insertAllData(model);
            EName.setText("");
            E_Des.setText("");
            E_Price.setText("");
            E_size.setText("");
            mImageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(""));
            Toast.makeText(this,"Succeed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Database of list**

```
public abstract DaoClass getDao();
private static DatabaseClass instance;

static DatabaseClass getDatabase(final Context context){

          if (instance == null){
              synchronized (DatabaseClass.class){
                  instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,DatabaseClass.class,"Database").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
              }
          }
          return instance;
    }

}
```

This is adapter

```
public UserAdapter(Context context,List<UserModel> list){
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new viewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Ename.setText(list.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.E_des.setText(list.get(position).getProductDisc());
        holder.E_size.setText(list.get(position).getProductSize());
        holder.E_Price.setText(list.get(position).getProductPrice());
        holder.MyPic.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImage());
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
    
    class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Ename,E_des,E_size,E_Price;
        ImageView MyPic;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Ename=itemView.findViewById(R.id.EName);
            E_des=itemView.findViewById(R.id.E_Des);
            E_size=itemView.findViewById(R.id.E_size);
            E_Price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.E_Price);
            MyPic=itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_Imaage);
    
    
        }
    }

}
```

I want to show all of this datas in recycler activity

Comment: To save images in local storage we need to use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() method.

Comment: Could you please write a example that where I could implement it ?